# Find maximum of a function 4

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I would appreciate if somebody could help me with the following problem

Q: Find the maximum of $$f(x) =\frac{x-\ln(1+x)}{x\ln(1+x)};\quad(x>0)$$

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you set the first derivative to $0$ and solved for $x$?

Comment: Hint: Splitting in two fractions simplifies the expression considerably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it has a tricky here. Indeed $f'（x）<0 \implies f_{max} =\lim_{x\to -1} f(x)=1$

$f'(x)<0 \iff \dfrac{1}{(x+1)(\rm{ln}(x+1))^2}>\dfrac{1}{x^2} \iff |\rm{ln}(x+1)|<\dfrac{|x|}{\sqrt{x+1}} \iff$

case 1: $x>0, \iff \rm{ln}(x+1)<\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{x+1}} $

$g(x)=\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{x+1}}-\rm{ln}(x+1),g'(x)=\dfrac{x+2-2\sqrt{x+1}}{2(x+1)^{\frac{3}{2}}}=\dfrac{(1-\sqrt{x+1})^2}{2(x+1)^{\frac{3}{2}}}>0 \implies g(x)\ge g(0)=0  \implies \rm{ln}(x+1)<\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{x+1}}$

case 2: $-1<x<0,\iff \rm{ln}(x+1)>\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{x+1}}$

$g'(x)>0 \implies g_{max}=g(0)=0 \implies g(x)<0 \implies  \rm{ln}(x+1)>\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{x+1}}$

so $f'(x)<0$

it may need to check the hole $f(0)=\dfrac{1}{2}$ ,that is OK.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Rerwite $f$ to $f(x)=\frac{1}{\rm{ln}(x+1)}-\frac{1}{x}$. You can consider $f'(x)=\frac{-1}{(x+1)(\rm{ln}(x+1))^2}+\frac{1}{x^2}$.